# CSS | Responsive menu

Tags: css, menu, responsive-design

I have a menu structure:

```
<ul id="nav_menu">
    <li><a href="#!index?category_id=3" class="subcategory">Electronics</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#!index?category_id=15">Mobile phones</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#!index?category_id=4">Computers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!index?category_id=5">Car Electronics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!index?category_id=6">TV &amp; Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!index?category_id=7">Cell Phones</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!index?category_id=8">MP3 Players</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!index?category_id=9">Cameras &amp; Photo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!index?category_id=10">Apparel</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!index?category_id=11">Music</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!index?category_id=12">Movies &amp; TV</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!index?category_id=13">Video Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!index?category_id=14">Office Supplies</a></li>
</ul>
```

But it looks like below:

[image]

Is it possible to optimize menu if I have a lot of categories and my device screen width is narrow?

My CSS:

```
#nav_menu li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 3px;
    position: relative;
}

#nav_menu > li > a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #404040;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav_menu ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #404040;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 36px;
    width: 140px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: How about off the shelf responsive menu solutions? I mean, do you have to use this design?

Answer (score 1):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mP4WZ/1/)**

**CSS**

```
#nav_menu ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
}
#nav_menu li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 3px;
    position: relative;
     border-bottom:#FFD700 3px solid;
}

#nav_menu > li > a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #404040;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-decoration: none;


}
#nav_menu ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #404040;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    width: 140px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba lo siguiente:

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/new6p0h8/)**

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("div.po").set_ELEMENT(
    {
        bgColor:'red',

        click: function(oThis)
        {
            oThis.find('> div').css({'color':'red','background-color' : 'blue'});
        }
     });
});
```